# Confusion around the "domain" tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently on Security.SE the [domain](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/domain) tag is being widely used as a synonym for both [dns](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dns) and [active-directory](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/active-directory).

Is there someway this can be cleaned up, or clarified?  Alternately, am I making much ado about nothing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, that's worth creating [dns-domain](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dns-domain) and [windows-domain](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-domain), then blacklisting [domain](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/domain) after we reorg those questions.

Comment: For the record, let's please be careful about retagging these. You don't want to do more than a handful at a time, and let them get to the bottom of the front page before doing another batch. Also look at the front page before doing a set in case someone else has already done some recently.

Comment: Why `windows-domain` if we have `active-directory`? Perhaps still change `domain` to `dns-domain`, but having both AD and windows-domain seems duplicate to me.

Comment: I second @Luc's comment, though I'm not sure we need [tag:dns-domain]. Isnt that what the `D` is for?? The [tag:domain] tag must die.

Comment: Okay, I went through the 'domain' questions and tagged the ones about domain controllers with 'active-directory' and the ones about dns and domain names with 'dns' and 'dns-domain'.

Comment: @Luc would it be appropriate to alias [tag:windows-domain] to [tag:active-directory] as well?

Comment: @jeffFerland Sounds good to me, I think they are identical in most cases (can't think of any where they aren't in security context).

Comment: @Luc Make [tag:dns-domain] and [tag:windows-domain] aliases (to [tag:dns] and [tag:active-directory] respectively). That way something comes up in autocompletion when someone types `domain` in the tag box.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest we use [dns](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dns) and [active-directory](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/active-directory) as our two tags, and blacklist [domain](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/domain) (perhaps with a tag wiki that recommends using [dns](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dns) or [active-directory](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/active-directory), depending).

Like AviD says, `dns-domain` seems redundant; `dns` seems fine.

Like Luc says, I don't think we need both `windows-domain` and `active-directory`.  We could have `windows-domain` be a synonym for `active-directory`, I suppose, but that seems unnecessary.

Comment: The advantage of having aliases is that they come up in autocompletion. Besides the fact that nobody reads tag wikis, you can't have a tag wiki for a tag with no question, so it isn't possible to attach guidance to an unused tag name.

Comment: @Gilles I read tag wikis